# How does one find the location of the a hard drive file in vmware?

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I have some prior experience with VirtualBox which I find to be pretty straight forward to use, it's easy to find the location of the harddrive file.  However in vmware it's proving difficult to find.

After going to `VM->Settings` in VMWare, and clicking on the `hardware` tab in the resulting window, and then selecting `disk1` from the tree panel, I expected to find the path to the `*.vmdk` file that contains the harddrive for purposes of backing it up.  But I was only presented with the name, and it is stored on some other harddrive somewhere.

How do I find the location of the `.vmdk`harddrive file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of your mounted VMFS datastores are mounted as subdirectories under `/vmfs/volumes`. You can get to them either by SSH/SCP or alternatively via the Datastore Browser in the vSphere Client.

If you're just going to be copying the files off for backup purposes, ensure that you stop or pause the VM before copying the files.

Comment: See: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RPrXp.png

Comment: @Zoredache That's the disk file textbox I was referring to...